# How to bulk index elasticsearch from Powershell with NEST client?

Tags: .net, powershell, api, elasticsearch, nest

I need to index many records from powershell but I am having issues writing that in powershell. Simple example is:

```
var bulkIndexResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
    .Index("people")
    .IndexMany(people)
);
```

In powershell I tried writing similar code but not sure how to transform `b => b`

```
PS C:\Users\svcacct> $client.Bulk($esrecords)
Cannot find an overload for "Bulk" and the argument count: "1".
```

I also had issues using method from config object before and in the end only `$config.GetType().GetMethod("DisableDirectStreaming").Invoke($config,$true)` worked. I am assuming it's again something similar but I simply don't know the PS equivalent.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the assembly, maybe link some information about it? For an awkward method, you can list the method's definition (and it's `[type]` requirements) with `($client | Get-Member Bulk).Definition` and see if there's a proper constructor like `[Name.Space.For.BulkIndexObject]::New('people','=>')`

Comment: I found out that I need to use .NET lambda expression written in powershell so I am trying to transform this in PS. I did something like `$client.Bulk{param($b) $b.IndexMany($esrecords)}` but getting error the body is missing. Probably my syntax is not good.

Comment: `($client | Get-Member Bulk).Definition
Nest.BulkResponse Bulk(System.Func[Nest.BulkDescriptor,Nest.IBulkRequest] selector), Nest.BulkResponse Bulk(Nest.IBulkRequest request), Nest.BulkResponse IElasticClient.Bulk(System.Func[Nest.BulkDescript
or,Nest.IBulkRequest] selector), Nest.BulkResponse IElasticClient.Bulk(Nest.IBulkRequest request)`

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/indexing-documents.html#_multiple_documents_with_bulk

Comment: Yeah, looks like you might need to build a request using something like `$request = New-Object Nest.IBulkRequest -argumentlist ($arg1, $arg2)`, then later do `$client.Bulk($request, '=>')`. There could also be another method, but you'd have to search their docs

Comment: I can't create IBulkRequest, but I can BulkRequest. Properties are all read only so I can't set them on object creation. I am stuck :/